# How to change UIPopoverPresentationController's arrow color without drawing my own

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller, uipopoverbackgroundview

I want to change the color of the arrow that `UIPopoverPresentationController` uses to point at its source. The only way I can see to do this is to subclass [`UIPopoverBackgroundView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverBackgroundView_class/) and write `drawRect` and draw the popover border and arrow myself. That's a pain, because there are little niceties in the default popover like rounded corners on everything. And I want to make it feel as much at home on the platform as I can.

Do I really have to draw my own popover arrow just to change the color of the arrow?

**Update:** I've tried setting the `backgroundColor` of the `UIPopoverPresentationController`, but it appears to change the color of everywhere the arrow might draw. I've seen it work before, but I can't nail down what makes it work when it does. See screenshot of setting the color to red. The blue is the content of the navigation controller in the popover. It's supposed to be pointing at the button.

[image: Popover background color issue]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `UIPopoverPresentationController`'s `backgroundColor` property should handle that for you

### Update

I've used this approach a number of times and have never seen what you have in your screenshot.  Are you sure you are using `popoverPresentationController.backgroundColor` and not setting a different background color on a view or container? Below is screenshot of non-centered popover arrow. The view controller background is green, the popoverPresentationController.backgroundColor is red. Shown next to the code setting the value.

[image: non-centered arrow on popover presentation controller]

### Update #2

I looked at the project you posted and found the problem (although I'm not entirely sure *why* it's the problem).  You are setting the popover presentation controller's `backgroundColor` property inside your presented view controller under `viewWillAppear:`.  I suspect that setting the background color like this *after* the presentation happened is what triggers the bug pre-iOS 10.

If you set the popover presentation controller's `backgroundColor` inside your presenting view controller's `onPopover:` method, where you are also setting the `sourceView` and `sourceRect` properties (and before you actually call `presentViewController:`), everything works correctly.

Comment: Wait, no. It only works if the arrow is centered. If the arrow is off-center it draws the color you set throughout the rect where the arrow would be.

Comment: And it also draws it in the corners where the content view controller's corners are rounded.

Comment: @TomHamming  That's really odd... please see my updated answer.  Are you setting some other properties on the popover presentation controller that might be conflicting?  I've used backgroundColor a number of times without issue in many different arrow positions.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/tomhamming/PopoverArrowColor) is my sample code on GitHub. Your solution does work like a charm on iOS 10.

Comment: I'm actually not sure it's being off-center that does it. My example project shows the issue even when the arrow is centered.

Comment: @TomHamming  I think I found a fix for you, updated my answer!

Comment: That indeed is the key! Thanks. It also appears that changing after presentation is complete is safe. It must be changing it while it's presenting that causes the issue. I'd file a radar, but iOS 10 is already fine.

Comment: @TomHamming  Very interesting! Thanks for that follow-up info.  It may save me some hair-pulling in the future